# Saving and Loading a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have implemented a simple way to write and read a python dictionary, however, I am having trouble understanding why it will not work as a function.

To save the dictionary I use this command:

```
def saveHash():
     print "Saving hash file to ./savedHash"
     f = open('savedHash','w')
     f.write(str(my_hash))
     f.close()
     print "Save Successfull"

saveHash()
```

This works perfectly fine. Now to load my dictionary within the script I do:

```
def loadHash(name):
     print "Loading hash file %s" % (name)
     f = open(name,'r')
     my_hash = eval(f.read())
     f.close()
     print "Hash loaded"

loadHash('savedHash')
```

The problem is that it does not seem to work within the script I am running, yet it will work inside the shell. If I have `savedHash` inside my directory `/home/dan/` and open a python shell inside that directory, then run `loadHash('savedHash')` or `loadHash('./savedHash')` or `loadHash('/home/dan/savedHash')` it does not populate the dictionary/hash. When I do `random.choice(my_hash.keys())` it fails and returns this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/projects/dan/software/Python-2.7.2/Lib/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However if I run command by command like:

```
>>> f = open(name,'r')
>>> my_hash = eval(f.read())
>>> f.close()
```

I can type `print random.choice(my_hash.keys())` and get a value out of it. Does anybody know why it won't work within the script but it will in the shell? I am using an argument parser to get the filename.

Comment: Why not use the `pickle` module?

Comment: I tried pickle before, it basically did the same thing or wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Just to point it out again, DO NOT USE `eval`! Use `json` or `pickle` instead, see my answer for a working `json` example.

Comment: @dan How exactly did `pickle` not work as expected for you?? I've not run into any issues, even with very very large dictionaries and sets, using pickle dump/load.

Comment: Actually looking back it was my fault, I just didn't want to import anything that I didn't need. Plus I thought it would be fun to try and do without...

Comment: Yes, opening a security hole bigger than the Atlantic instead of rely on trusted code from the standard library is really "fun".

Comment: I will clean up my code, and refrain from eval, probably use pickle

Comment: @Dan If you have only dictionaries, `json` is much faster than `pickle` (here is [a benchmark](http://kovshenin.com/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/)).

Comment: @ms4py thats pretty neat about the json data loading so much faster than pickle ... I had no idea.... any idea how json stacks up against cPickle off hand

Comment: @JoranBeasley apparently JSON is still twice as fast when compared to cPickle, see bottom of benchmark link provided by ms4py

Comment: @casperOne I didn't realize this, but I did notice another comment on the answer below `Downvoter: Care to explain? This looks like a good solution to me. – mgilson 19 hours ago`. So I just assumed asking what was wrong with my question would be appropriate. I won't be able to correct my mistakes unless I get feedback. Though seemingly counter-intuitive, I will refrain from this in the future.

Comment: @dan You can ask what's wrong with your question without talking about votes.  Asking what is wrong with the question is fine, and acceptable, but remove the vote aspect from it.  In regards to the other comments, I was looking at a flag on the question, but I'll clear up those comments now as well.

Comment: Understood, I can see why. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, do NEVER use `eval` from an untrusted source (like a file)!

I would suggest storing a dictionary with `json`:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'a': 3}
>>> with open('data.txt', 'w') as fobj:
...   json.dump(d, fobj)
... 
>>> with open('data.txt') as fobj:
...   d2 = json.load(fobj)
... 
>>> d2
{u'a': 3}
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question, even if you are 200% correct.

Comment: @jadkik94 The question is "Saving and Loading a dictionary in Python" ;)

Comment: I read the "Does anybody know why it won't work within the script but it will in the shell?" part :P

Comment: Thats why the top answer is the accepted one. The rest are suggestions on my coding, though they may be valid, they are not answers to the question I was asking.

Comment: What is with the extra `u` in the dictionary?

Comment: May not be what the asker was looking for, but 3 years later, it's exactly what I'm looking for. +1

Answer (score 2):

It is because in the save function, `my_hash` is assumed global and taken from the global namespace, which is what you expect. However, the second function does not know you are talking about a global variable. So you should add to the top of your function `global my_hash`.

A better solution is to pass the hash as an argument to the function to save it. And return it when loading:

```
def saveHash(my_hash):
    # ...

def loadHash():
    # ...
    return my_hash

# Usage:
saveHash(my_hash)
my_hash = loadHash()
```

Comment: Agreed, thanks I took the advice to return a hash from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadHash()` function doesn't return anything, so the `myHash` variable disappears when the function ends.

If you're trying to populate a global variable `myHash`, as pointed out in other answers, you need to include the line `global myHash` inside the function. See also the reasons to avoid global variables when possible.

Also see the notes in the other answers about avoiding `eval()`

Comment: If the variable is previously defined in the global aspect, wouldn't it populate it?

Comment: @Dan If you declare the variable as `global`, it should populate it.  But, globals are generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Dan, no, it won't!  Writing to global variables is easy to do by accident but almost never what you want to do on purpose, so when you really do want to do it on purpose, you have to declare the variable as a global with the `global` keyword within your function first.

Comment: Indeed, global variables can cause problems. But if you want to use it, you need to put `global my_hash` in the function prior to doing anything with the variable. Otherwise it will look for (or create) a new variable `my_hash` in the local scope, which will be completely unrelated to the variable `my_hash` that's in the global scope.